# Perform a join query using Doctrine Query Builder

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I want to not show a product in my index page if the quantity of that product equal to 1. The quantity of the product is store in the table Quantity. The table quantity is link to product (ManyToOne).

This is what i have done.

```
 public function product($id)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->leftJoin('e.quantity', 'r')
            ->where('r.quantity = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->getQuery();

        return $query->getResult();
    }
```

**Quantity**

```
 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $desk2;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $quantity;
```

**Product**

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */

private $id;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="telephone", type="string", length=30)
 */
private $telephone;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=125)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text" , length=125)
 */
private $description;
```

**index**

```
 public function indexvAction($id)
    {

        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $findEntities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->product($id);
        $entity = $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate($findEntities, $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1), 9
        );
        if ($session->has('cart'))
            $cart = $session->get('cart');
        else
            $cart = false;
        return $this->render('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:indexv.html.twig', array('entity' => $entity,
            'cart' => $cart));
    }
```

**EDIT:**

default: **index.html.twig**

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}
        {% block newadvert %}
                <div class="span4 offset1">
                </div>
                {{ render(controller('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:indexv')) }}
        {% endblock newadvert %}
```

**controller:**

```
  public function indexAction()
  {

    return $this->render('FLYPlatformBundle:Default:index.html.twig');


  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only return products with quantities > 1 (or whatever quantity parameter you pass).

```
 public function product($quantityLimit)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->join('e.quantity', 'r')
            ->addSelect('r')
            ->where('r.quantity > :quantityLimit')
            ->setParameter('quantityLimit', $quantityLimit)
            ->getQuery();

        return $query->getResult();
    }
```

If you wanted to return all products, but only quantities where they are > 1 you would use a leftJoin like so.

```
 public function product($quantityLimit)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->leftJoin('e.quantity', 'r', 'WITH', 'r.quantity > :quantityLimit')
            ->addSelect('r')
            ->setParameter('quantityLimit', $quantityLimit)
            ->getQuery();

        return $query->getResult();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. i tried what you suggested,but i have this error: `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Controller "FLY\BookingsBundle\Controller\PostController::indexvAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$quantityLimit" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).") in FLYPlatformBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 5.` I updated my post on top with the default index.html.twig

Comment: You need to pass the quantityLimit parameter to your indexvAction - that's not a problem with the query, just how you call your route. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#routing-with-placeholders and ensure you are calling your controller method correctly. E.g. http://yoursite.com/yourproductroute/1 - or something like that.

Comment: I already pass the quantityLimit parameter in my indexvAction. The page indexv.html.twig is render in the page index.html.twig. And i think the problem come from this line :    `{{ render(controller('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:indexv')) }} `

Comment: Ah yup, you still have to pass the controller argument as usual. E.g. {{ render(controller('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:indexv', {'quantityLimit': 1})) }}

Comment: I made it work by adding this line in my repository:    `->Where('e.quantity = 1')` Thank you so much Richard for you help. I really appreciate it.